# Retrieve excel file stored in sql server using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a desktop application using vb.net, to process some excel files, those files are stored in a sql server database.
Here is the code I have:

```
Try
        conDCS.Open()
        comDCS.Connection = conDCS
        comDCS.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        comDCS.CommandText = "select top 2 [Filename], [File] " & _
                            "from tblFiles (nolock) " & _
                            "where ([Filename] like 'DIG%' or [Filename] like 'FAC%') and " & _
                            "(UploadDate>='" & FromDate & "' and UploadDate<'" & ToDate & "')"
        comDCS.ExecuteNonQuery()
        rdrDCS = comDCS.ExecuteReader
        If rdrDCS.HasRows Then
            While rdrDCS.Read
                Dim imageInBytes As Byte() = rdrDCS(1)
                Dim memoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(imageInBytes, False)
                Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
                image.Save(TempPath & rdrDCS(0))
            End While
            ToProcess = True
        End If
        rdrDCS.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ToProcess = False
        MessageBox.Show("Error accessing to the files: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        conDCS.Close()
    End Try
```

I'm getting: "Parameter is not valid" in this line:

```
Dim image As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream)
```

I have understood that this error is related to an invalid image data, but I can't figure it out what could be the problem.

imageInBytes has a length of 41473. And some items of the array have zero as value.

What could be wrong here, or perhaps, can anyone supply a working code to achieve this?

Comment: You say you're processing Excel files, but then you're trying to stream the data into an image file.  What are you reading form the database, an Excel file or an Image file?

Comment: I just was looking at that, in the DB is stored in a field type image, but it is a xls file, and at the time to retrieve it I'm using an image as System.drawing.Image, that must be the problem, what should I put there for an excel file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use a common method to save a file from a database field to a file:

```
Public Function FieldToFile(ByVal sFileName As String, ByVal theField As Object) As Boolean
    ' Exceptions are handled by the caller

    If theField IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        Using oStream As New System.IO.FileStream(sFileName, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
            If oStream IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim aBytes As Byte()

                aBytes = DirectCast(theField, Byte())

                oStream.Write(aBytes, 0, aBytes.Length)
                oStream.Close()
            End If
        End Using
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

This can be called as follows:

```
Call FieldToFile(someFileName, rdrDCS(1)
```